# How to trigger a multi-branch Jenkins pipeline when artifact is published in Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm trying to trigger a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline using the "Artifactory Trigger" plugin.

I have set the "Enable Artifactory Trigger" in jenkins multi-branch Pipeline as follows but even when new artifacts are published to the path that is being watched, I never have a new Jenkins job triggered.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to set something up on the Artifactory end too?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multibranch triggering is supported since Jenkins Artifactory plugin 3.12.1. ([Release notes](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in#JenkinsArtifactoryPlug-in-ReleaseNotes))

By looking at your screenshot, I suspect that your version is lower than that.
It looks like the `Branches to trigger` field is missing:
[image: Multibranch pipeline trigger]

Read more about triggering pipelines here:

1. [Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in#JenkinsArtifactoryPlug-in-TriggeringBuilds)
2. [Scripted pipeline example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/build-trigger-example/Jenkinsfile)
3. [Declarative pipeline example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/build-trigger-example/Jenkinsfile)